# Why doesn't Alignment->Center work in SetOptions?

Tags: graphics, front-end

This follows on my previous question that was kindly solved by a fellow member.

```
data = Reverse[Sort[RandomReal[1, 5]]];
Module[{t = 0, len = Length[data], sum = Total[data]}, 
 Graphics[Table[{Hue[i/len], EdgeForm[Opacity[.8]], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {t, t += 2 Pi data[[i]]/sum}]}, {i, len}]]]

SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], Background -> Red,
  Alignment -> Center]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alignment` is not an option for `Cell`:

```
Options[Cell Alignment]
```

[image]

Use [`TextAlignment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextAlignment.html) instead:

```
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, CellGroup]
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[EvaluationNotebook[]], Background -> Red,
  TextAlignment -> Center]
```

[image]

[image]